# Using an imported Jar file that accesses its own R$string values

Tags: android, jar

I have a supplied .jar library that is under a different package and it attempts to access string resources in its own package. While the strings.xml is not inside the jar file how can I get com.itspackagename.R to work inside the .jar file when the service starts?

I am getting the following type of error.

```
04-03 11:31:41.798 1791-1791/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.mypackage, PID: 1791
                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/otherpackagename/R$string;
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.otherpackagename.R$string" on path:
```

To me it looks like it is trying to access its own .R which is failing. I don't know if/how to fix this if I can simply put the string resources into my strings.xml?, place them inside the jar,or provide another strings.xml in another location, or if its an issue with it resolving its own resources (R) ?

Comment: A JAR does not have Android resources.

Comment: So, the jar that is trying to access R$string simply won't work as a jar then?

Comment: Or if the .jar used the same package name as my application would it be able to access my string resources?